# Weight distribution of a random linear code

Tags: coding-theory

Is there any formula to express the weight distribution of a random binary  linear code?. When I say weight, this means number of non-zero entries, i.e.Hamming Weight.

Comment: Do you mean among codes of fixed length and rank?

Comment: fixed length and rank

Comment: The weight distribution of a random code follows the binomial distribution closely. In other words, the expected number of words of weight $m, 0\le m\le n$, in a code of length $n$ and rank $k$ is  $2^{k-n}\binom nm$.